# I need to accesss my Desktop computer over local LAN via tablet or laptop, what software can do this effeciently?

Tags: windows, remote-access, remote-desktop

I need to access my desktop via local LAN using a windows tablet or laptop, what software do you recommend?
Desktop has Windows Home.
Main usage is: accessing large PDFs / possible gaming.

Comment: Do you just want to access the files, as if they were on another drive (e.g `P:\`)?  Of do you want to see the desktop's screen from the tablet or laptop and be able to use the remote keyboard * mouse to access it?

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica - A very good question, though I might assume from the [tag:remote-desktop] tag that the querent wants to be able to use the remote keyboard and mouse to work on it like it was in front of him (e.g., RDP-, Dameware-, or VNC-style)

Comment: You say "from a tablet"... in addition to the question @MawgsaysreinstateMonica asks, what sort of tablet are you using? iPad, Android, Surface, ...?

Comment: If you go for Windows Remote Desktop, I think cannot use login-free access. WIndows forces you to disable this feature. You must create a user and a passwort,  for the login-screen. Otherwise, everyone in your network would have free access to your computer. But I'm not sure if that's the case for your version of Windows Home.

Comment: I chose to go with the old WorkGroups and had to chose a password for my server, but I only needed too set my laptop up once to access the drives remotely Good point, though (upvote).

Answer (score 2):

If you want a slick and professional app, look into [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/), which is available for Windows, Linux, Max, Android, iOs, Chrome OS and Raspberry Pi, which ought to cover all possibilities.

It is free for non-commercial use.

TeamViewer will let you have remote access from one device to another and will let you use the keyboard/mouse/touch controls of the controlling device to control the controlled device.

---

If you do not like the idea of your data going through a corporation's servers, then consider some form of [Virtual Network COmputing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) (VNC) to get a direct connection, instead of sandwiching TeamViewer's server between your devices.

Wikipedia has a [comparison of remote desktop software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software).

Speaking form personal experience, I have been happy for decades with [TightVNC](https://www.tightvnc.com/), which I use provately and have also used in systems which I have sold to industry.

There is a server version for Windows, Linux & Mac, so that will cover your desktop with the PDF files, they also have a viewer for Android & iOs.

That should be enough for you, and involves no 3rd party server, which might access your data, but feel free to look at other VNCs.

---

All of the above solutions have built-in file transfer software, to allow you copy some of those PDFs after viewing them in-situ.

---

But, even those might be overkill. Windows has the built-in ability to access a directory on a remote PC with a driver letter.

Thus, my home server had a directory `d:\backups`, which appears to my laptop as `b:`.

That is probably the simplest solution, and would work for " `accessing large PDFs`", but probably ***not*** "possible gaming" - depending on what you mean by that. If you just want to run an executable from the desktop on a laptop, then, yes, this will work. If you have a login for an internet game on the desktop, then you may not be able to launch it and control it from an Android tablet.

If interested, DuckDuckGo for [Windows HomeGroup](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/homegroup-from-start-to-finish-9f802c8c-900f-60fb-826f-6fe06add8fe9) and/or [Windows WorkGroup](https://www.tomshardware.com/uk/news/how-to-set-up-join-workgroup-windows-10,36843.html).

Since those are part of the o/s, you should ask further questions on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).